# Assign HTML tags to a variable

Tags: html, bash

Just a quick question guys. I would like to assign html tags to a variable in BASH. How do i do this?

Or is there a better way to do this?

This is the actual portion of the code:

```
function storage_util_1942
{
  if [ $SETFLAG_1942 = "YES" ];
  then

  for i in {1..5}
  do
  TMPSTOR=$(cat $HCREPORT1942 | grep -A$i DISK | tail -1)
  RULESET=$(cat $HCREPORT1942 | grep -A$i DISK | tail -1 | awk '{print $6}' | cut -d'%' -f1)

  if [ $RULESET -gt 90 ]
  then
    STORAGE$i="<font color=\"red\"><b>${TMPSTOR}</b></font>"
  else
    STORAGE$i="<font color=\"green\"><b>${TMPSTOR}</b></font>"
  fi
  done

fi

echo "  <tr align="left">"
echo "    <td><font face="verdana,helvetica" size="1" color="red"><b>Storage Capacity <font color="green">[Must be less than 90%]</b></font></td>"
echo "  </tr>"
echo "  <tr align="left" bgcolor="white" height="80">"
echo "    <td><font face="courier new" size="1" color="black">"
echo "      <br>"
echo "      <pre>"
echo "       $STORAGE1"
echo "       $STORAGE2"
echo "       $STORAGE3"
echo "       $STORAGE4"
echo "       $STORAGE5"
echo "      </pre></font>"
echo "    </td>"
echo "  </tr>"
```

}

This is part of an HTML base reporting that I am creating. The objective is to display the value of $STORAGE(#) base on the condition set above. RED if it is above 90 and GREEN otherwise.

When I tried to run the script it still give me the "No such file or directory" error:

```
+++ storage_util_1942
+++ '[' YES = YES ']'
+++ for i in '{1..5}'
++++ cat /apps/data/support_bin/monitoring/healthcheck/healthcheck.report
++++ grep -A1 DISK
++++ tail -1
+++ TMPSTOR='/dev/mapper/rootdg-rootdgvol2   ext3   1.9G  1.7G  133M   93%   /var'
++++ cat /apps/data/support_bin/monitoring/healthcheck/czchols1942.healthcheck.report
++++ grep -A1 DISK
++++ tail -1
++++ awk '{print $6}'
++++ cut -d% -f1
+++ RULESET=93
+++ '[' 93 -gt 90 ']'
+++ 'STORAGE1=<font color="red"><b>/dev/mapper/rootdg-rootdgvol2   ext3   1.9G  1.7G  133M   93%   /var</b></font>'

./script.sh: line 166: STORAGE1=<font color="red"><b>/dev/mapper/rootdg-rootdgvol2   ext3   1.9G  1.7G  133M   93%   /var</b></font>: No such file or directory
```

The evaluation before the last line is already correct but how come it evaluates the value as if it is executed? I should only stay as a value and not a command.

Thanks,

Comment: The better way would involve not using `<font>`, for one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need quotes around the variable assignments, and since your values have double-quotes (and no other variables referenced), I would use single quotes:

`var='<font color="red">HELLO WORLD</font>'`

If you need to interpret other variables within the assignment, you need to use double-quotes, escaping any literal ones:

`var="<font color=\"red\">${TMPSTOR}</font>"`

You also need to use arrays for your "dynamically-named" variables:

`STORAGE[$i]="..."`

`echo "$STORAGE[1]"` ...

The bigger question is what you're really trying to do with this. Why are you using a `<font>` tag, why aren't you just setting a CSS class as the variable (since that's the only difference in the HTML), etc.

Comment: hi brian, i already tried using quotes and i am getting error message: no such file or directory

Comment: i am basically trying to modify/update the text in the HTML if a certain rule/condition is met. I have to do this for quite a number of places in the page

Comment: @Ravenwolf - if you are only getting that error message when using the quotes, be sure you are using straight single quotes, not backticks. Backticks try to execute the contents as bash commands.

Comment: hi brian, i am using single quotes

Comment: @Ravenwolf, maybe you should edit your post to include the version with quotes too. There must be something else wrong if it's not the quotes themselves. If you copy/paste the line of code in my answer and run it at the bash prompt, it works, right?

Comment: yes you are correct. I did simulate it too before in the command prompt and the output is what I expected it. but when i use it in my script is giving me error.

Comment: @Ravenwolf, please post the exact code snippet from your script. I just ran this code (adding the quotes) as a script, and it works. It must be something else.

Comment: hi brian i just updated my post. by the way, thanks for your help on this.

Comment: @Ravenwolf, I just updated my answer, seeing that you do have variables to be interpreted within the text. You should use double quotes. It looks like the real problem is with the `echo` statements because they also don't escape the literal double-quotes within them.

Comment: hi brian, i have just added the result of my testing

Comment: @Ravenwolf - I think I have the final piece to your problem: you can't name variables the way you are doing (`STORAGE$i`). You need an array: `STORAGE[$i]`. If this works, please "accept" my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of things in the script segment you've posted that could be done in "a better way".  Here's a sampling of them.

1. *Don't use unnecessary pipes.*  `awk` will do everything that `grep`, `tail` and `cut` will do, without launching extra processes for each step through the pipeline.

   ```
   TMPSTOR=$(awk -vi="$i" '/DISK/{n=i+1} {n--} n==0 {print;exit}' $HCREPORT1942)
   ```
2. *Use quotes around variables.*  You've included `if [ $SETFLAG_1942 = "YES" ];` which is backwards.  The thing you want to protect in quotes is the variable, not the text that is hard-coded into the script.
3. You're using dynamic variable naming.  This is a Bad Thing, as it usually requires use of `eval`, which is evil.

   ```
   eval STORAGE$i="'<font color=\"red\"><b>\${TMPSTOR}</b></font>'"
   ```

   So instead of `STORAGE$i=...`, use an array.

   ```
   declare -a STORAGE
   if [ -n "${RULESET//[0-9]/}" ]; then
     # RULESET contains non-digts, which it should not.
     echo "ERROR: invalid data, please investigate." >&2
     exit 1
   elif [ "$RULESET" -gt 90 ]; then
     STORAGE[$i]="<span class='warn'>${TMPSTOR}</span>"
   else
     STORAGE[$i]="<span class='good'>${TMPSTOR}</span>"
   fi
   ```

   Then walk through the array with something like:

   ```
   for item in ${STORAGE[@]}; do
     echo "$item"
   done
   ```
4. And finally, your HTML needs to be improved, but that's off-topic for this question.

Comment: thanks ghoti, this is great. my script is quite crude at the moment since it is done in haste. i'll take your suggestions in consideration